# Find $\int (\ln(x))^x p'(x) dx$ , where $p(x)=x\ln(\ln(x))$

Tags: integration

This is a 2 part question so bear with me! (Stuck on the second part).

> > $Q1(a)$ If $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are real functions of $x$ show that when $h(x) = \left[f(x)\right]^{g(x)}$ then $h'(x)=  \left[f(x)\right]^{g(x)} \left(g'(x)ln[f(x)]+g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)$

What I have done:

Consider

$$h(x) = \left[f(x)\right]^{g(x)}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \ln(h(x)) = g(x) \ln [f(x)]$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{h'(x)}{h(x)} = g'(x)\ln [f(x)] + g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow h'(x) = h(x)\left(g'(x)ln[f(x)]+g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)$$

$$ \therefore h'(x) = \left[f(x)\right]^{g(x)} \left(g'(x)ln[f(x)]+g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)$$

> > $Q1(b)$ Using the super-power rule in part (a) above , or otherwise find
> >
> > $$\int (\ln(x))^x p'(x) dx $$ Where $p(x)=x\ln(\ln(x))$

This is the part where I am stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(\log x)^x = \mathrm{e}^{x \log \log x}$.  Your integrand is $\mathrm{e}^{p(x)}p'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

One may observe that
$$
\int (\ln(x))^x p'(x) dx=\int e^{x(\ln(\ln x))}\left(x(\ln(\ln x))\right)' dx=\int e^u du
$$ with the change of variable $u=x(\ln(\ln x))$.